# Change the $_FILES to Magento2 standard

Tags: magento2.2, file-upload

When using below code getting "Direct use of $_FILES Superglobal detected" error. Can anyone suggest how to use in Magento2.

```
$file = $_FILES["r_dea_license"]["name"]; 
            $array = explode('.', $file);
            $fileName=$array[0];
            $fileExt=$array[1];
            $deaFile='d_'.$fileName."_".time().".".$fileExt;
            $uploader = $this->_fileUploaderFactory->create(['fileId' => 'r_dea_license']);
            $uploader->setAllowRenameFiles(true);
            $uploader->setFilesDispersion(false);
            $uploader->save($media, $deaFile);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this code:**

```
try{
    $uploader = $this->_uploaderFactory->create(['fileId' => 'image']);
    $uploader->setAllowedExtensions(['jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif', 'png']);
    $imageAdapter = $this->_objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Image\AdapterFactory')->create();
    $uploader->setAllowRenameFiles(true);
    $uploader->setFilesDispersion(true);
    $mediaDirectory = $this->_objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Filesystem')
        ->getDirectoryRead(DirectoryList::MEDIA);
    $result = $uploader->save($mediaDirectory->getAbsolutePath('gallery/images'));
        if($result['error']==0)
        {
            echo $result['file'];
        }
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    $this->messageManager->addSuccess($e->getMessage());
}
```

Comment: I need to explode the file 
$file = $_FILES["r_dea_license"]["name"]; 
            $array = explode('.', $file);
            $fileName=$array[0];
            $fileExt=$array[1];
            $deaFile='d_'.$fileName."_".time().".".$fileExt;
            $uploader = $this->_fileUploaderFactory->create(['fileId' => 'r_dea_license']);
            $uploader->setAllowRenameFiles(true);
            $uploader->setFilesDispersion(false);
            $uploader->save($media, $deaFile);